How to preserve layer transparency when creating virtual layers in QGIS?
I have about 500 raster layers. I have applied transparency settings (deleting the background white color) to all of these layers. Now I want to merge all these layers without losing resolution by creating a virtual raster layer. This process is successful. However, when merging the layers, the transparency of the layers is ignored. This causes distortions in the image. How can I merge the layers while preserving their transparency?
Before merging two old maps:

#############################################
After merging two old maps (Transparency settings ignored):

